# Validacion de JavaScript no funciona en Iphone

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un menu en el cual la validacion para movil en los dispositivos IOS (iPhone) no me estaria funcionando pero en Android si, cual sera el motivo/causa de esto?
En Live Server se ve perfectamente en la laptop en version movil se ve como va cambiando las cosas y el JavaScript este funcionando, pero al entrar en Live Server desde el celular (iPhone) no funciona. Si alguien fuera tan amable en decirme como podria solucionar este problema.
Es problema de iPhone del safari o es algun error que he cometido yo, ya que en un dispositivo android me anda a la perfeccion?

```js
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)")) {
    let $botonMenu = document.querySelector("#icono_menu");
    let $icono_menu = document.querySelector("#bar_menu");
    $botonMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let $menu = document.querySelector("#nav_menu");
      if ($icono_menu.className == "fas fa-bars") {
        $menu.style.display = "flex";
        $icono_menu.className = "fas fa-close";
      } else if ($icono_menu.className == "fas fa-close") {
        $icono_menu.className = "fas fa-bars";
        $menu.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  }
```

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background-color: rgba(233, 230, 230, 0.521);
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .container__header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 20px;
  }
  .icono_menu_mobile {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .logo img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .menu > nav {
    background-color: #777b7d;
    width: 100vw;
    height: fit-content;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  .menu > nav > ul {
    gap: 10px;
  }
  .menu > .socialMedia{
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
  }
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="container__header">
            
            <div class="icono_menu_mobile" id="icono_menu">
                <i id="bar_menu" class="fas fa-bars" ></i>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/logo-removebg-preview.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <nav id="nav_menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="inicio__activo"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Catalogo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Adopcion</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>


                <div class="socialMedia">
                    <a href="#">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!--! Font Awesome Free 6.4.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. --><path d="M416 208c0 45.9-14.9 88.3-40 122.7L502.6 457.4c12.5 12.5 12.5 32.8 0 45.3s-32.8 12.5-45.3 0L330.7 376c-34.4 25.2-76.8 40-122.7 40C93.1 416 0 322.9 0 208S93.1 0 208 0S416 93.1 416 208zM208 352a144 144 0 1 0 0-288 144 144 0 1 0 0 288z"/></svg>                    </a>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!--! Font Awesome Free 6.4.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. --><path d="M304 128a80 80 0 1 0 -160 0 80 80 0 1 0 160 0zM96 128a128 128 0 1 1 256 0A128 128 0 1 1 96 128zM49.3 464H398.7c-8.9-63.3-63.3-112-129-112H178.3c-65.7 0-120.1 48.7-129 112zM0 482.3C0 383.8 79.8 304 178.3 304h91.4C368.2 304 448 383.8 448 482.3c0 16.4-13.3 29.7-29.7 29.7H29.7C13.3 512 0 498.7 0 482.3z"/></svg>
                    </a>
                        <a href="#">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!--! Font Awesome Free 6.4.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. --><path d="M160 112c0-35.3 28.7-64 64-64s64 28.7 64 64v48H160V112zm-48 48H48c-26.5 0-48 21.5-48 48V416c0 53 43 96 96 96H352c53 0 96-43 96-96V208c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48H336V112C336 50.1 285.9 0 224 0S112 50.1 112 112v48zm24 48a24 24 0 1 1 0 48 24 24 0 1 1 0-48zm152 24a24 24 0 1 1 48 0 24 24 0 1 1 -48 0z"/></svg>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Te da algun error??